# Repeat list field element when select menu in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I am creating a blackberry application. In this I am using custom list. when I select a menu item choice then first time it works fine and I select again menu it again add list elements.

I want to show one time list element not repeat elements by clicking again again.

How to remove previous elements of list.

My code is here

```
    public class SecondScreen extends MainScreen  {

/*private LabelField tab1;
private LabelField tab2;
private LabelField tab3;*/

private CustomButton tab1;
private CustomButton tab2;
private CustomButton tab3;
private LabelField spacer1;
private LabelField spacer2;
private VerticalFieldManager tabArea;
private LabelField tab1Heading;
private BasicEditField tab1Field1;
private BasicEditField tab1Field2;
private LabelField tab2Heading;
private BasicEditField tab2Field1;
private BasicEditField tab2Field2;
private LabelField tab3Heading;
private BasicEditField tab3Field1;
private BasicEditField tab3Field2;
private VerticalFieldManager tab1Manager;
private VerticalFieldManager tab2Manager;
private VerticalFieldManager tab3Manager;
private BitmapField bmpfield;
private LabelField title;
static Font fontTitleTop;
//XmlParse parse;
ListField myList;



public SecondScreen() {



    fontTitleTop = Font.getDefault().derive(Font.BOLD, 25);

    final Bitmap logo = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("title_bg.png");
    HorizontalFieldManager hM = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_TOP|Field.FIELD_HCENTER)
    {
        public void paintBackground(Graphics g)
        {
            g.drawBitmap(0,0,Display.getHorizontalResolution(),50,logo,0,0);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.setFont(SecondScreen.fontTitleTop);
            if(Display.getWidth()>=360){
                g.drawText("Category",((Display.getWidth()/14)),10,0);
            }
            super.paintBackground(g);
        }            

        protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) 
        {

            setExtent(maxWidth, 50);

        }

    };

    //hM.add(title);
    add(hM);



}

protected void makeMenu(Menu menu, int instance)
{
    super.makeMenu(menu, instance);
    menu.add(new MenuItem("Rss",10,10) {

        public void run() {

            String url = "http://192.168.0.118/rss_new/categories.xml";
            XmlParse.category.removeAllElements();

            XmlParse xp = new XmlParse();
            xp.getDetails(url);

           myList = new MyListField(XmlParse.category);
            myList.setSize(XmlParse.category.size());
            System.out.println("Xml Parsing");
            add(myList);

        }
    });

    menu.add(new MenuItem("Fav",10,10) {

        public void run() {

            System.out.println("Fav. List");

        }
    });
}




private class MyListField extends ListField implements ListFieldCallback
{


    private Vector content = new Vector();
    private Vector content2 = new Vector();
    MyListField  list ;


    public MyListField(Vector content) {

        this.content = content;
        }

    public void drawListRow(ListField listField, Graphics graphics,
            int index, int y, int width) {

        list = (MyListField)listField;

        String title = content.elementAt(index).toString();
        System.out.println("Content "+title+" at index"+ index);

        TableManager tm = new TableManager(title, index);
        tm.drawRow(graphics, 0, y, width, listField.getRowHeight());


    }

    public Object get(ListField listField, int index) {

        return null;
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth(ListField listField) {

        return 0;
    }

    public int indexOfList(ListField listField, String prefix, int start) {

        return 0;
    }

protected  boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) 
    {

          int selectedIndex = list.getSelectedIndex();
        System.out.print("List selected index ::"+selectedIndex);
        ThirdScreen thirdScreen = new ThirdScreen(selectedIndex);
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(thirdScreen);



        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: @BB Expert I am taking reference of this link http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Custom-ListField-row-with-images-and-text/td-p/227993

Comment: So which code you have implement...

Comment: @BBExpert I am implement table manager class code.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating your `MenuItem`s in `makeMenu()` which is called every time the screen needs to display the menu. This means every time the user presses the menu button you create fresh menu items which are added to the previously created menu items, hence the duplicates.

Move your MenuItem create code inside the constructor for your screen. Since the constructor is only called once, you won't have to worry about duplicate MenuItems being created.

To add menu items in the constructor just use `addMenuItem(MenuItem)`

Note that there's no need to override `makeMenu` now so you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

First thing in `makeMenu` (or second, if you want to call `super.makeMenu`) should be the sentence:

```
menu.deleteAll();
```

Otherwise, each time you push the menu button, new entries are added in addition to the ones already present.